# Utility Function - Calculating consumer surplus

Tags: calculus, education, economics

> Consider the utility function $U(X_1, X_2) = X_1X_2$. Assume that the consumer has budget $M=18$, that the prices are $p1 = p2 = 1$ to start, and that the price of good $1$ rises to $p1 = 2.25$. Find the loss of consumer's surplus resulting from the rise in $p1$. Round the answer to one decimal place.

I'm working through a sample question as part of my microeconomics class, I have worked out the consumers demand function for good $X_1$ is

$$X_1 = \frac{m}{2p1}$$

I don't know how to find the loss of consumer's surplus from this. Any help would with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can pose the question on Economics SE, it would be much better suited. You might also get an answer to it there. https://economics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you very much, @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost

Comment: You are welcome.